# Solaris recovery and home: what I miss?

Tags: solaris

I need to recovery solaris11,the incorrect permission of user( some bad thing with uid..) cannot allow ssh!

So I did

```
reboot
```

boot from cd-installation select language and then shell

I import my rpool OK

```
zpool import -f rpool
```

I mount my BE

```
beadm mount -b mybe /mnt
```

I chroot on /mnt

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Then I correct the permission and..OK

```
usermod -u 109 myuser
```

Now I want to apply on homedir..

```
chown -R myuser /export/home/myuser
```

But export/home is empty!

```
zpool list
zpool status
```

Report no error.
What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found

```
zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/export/home export/home

mount /mnt/export/home
```

I made my changes

```
chroot /mnt
chown myuser /export/home/myuser
```

then exit,and reset mountpoint

```
zfs set mountpoint=/export/home export/home
beadm umount mybe
```

Reboot and works